# rdiff-backup tempdir appears to be empty

Tags: rdiff-backup

I recently had a problem with restoring an incremental snapshot using **rdiff-backup** where my main drive ran out of space.  After setting `--tempdir` as discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9951/rdiff-backup-and-running-out-of-disk-space-something-weirds-going-on), the problem went away and while restoring I can see bytes diminishing with `df -h` on the specified path's device.

Oddly, the actual path I set appears to be completely empty. Neither `ls` nor `du` indicates that there is anything at all occupying the path in question.

Is anyone here familiar enough with the inner workings of **rdiff-backup** to shed some light on where the temp files are actually being written?  And how is it that they seem to be invisible?

Comment: `--tempdir` appears to be straight-up ignored for me (`rdiff-backup` v2.0.5); no tempfiles are created and `rdiff-backup` instead fills RAM and swap and then dies when they're exhausted :(